# c# oracle procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, procedure

Я пытаюсь получит данные из этого  функции но получаю ошибку

```
    ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 330:
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:


     string sql = @"declare v_return varchar2(200);begin v_return  := ode.get_borc(:i_sozlesme_no,:i_aboncode,:i_abontype,:i_transactionid,:i_messagetype,:i_date,:i_time,:i_subdomain_name,:i_user_id,:i_password,:o_messagetype,:o_responsecode,:o_aboncode,:o_transactionid,:o_abontype,:o_namesurname,:o_debt,:o_date,:o_time); end; ";

        int rowsAffected = 0;
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 30000;
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;


        string o_messagetype = string.Empty;
        string o_responsecode = string.Empty;
        string o_aboncode = string.Empty;
        string o_transactionid = string.Empty;
        string o_abontype = string.Empty;
        string o_namesurname = string.Empty;
        string o_debt = string.Empty;
        string o_date = string.Empty;
        string o_time = string.Empty;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_sozlesme_no", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "10230252", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_aboncode", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "0700713200270", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_abontype", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "A", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_transactionid", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "1000947243", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_messagetype", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "1", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_date", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "12.11.2014", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_time", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "04:11:00", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_subdomain_name", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "modenis.azersu.az", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_user_id", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "101", ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("i_password", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, "modenis.azersu.az", ParameterDirection.Input);


        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_messagetype", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_messagetype, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_responsecode", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_responsecode, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_aboncode", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_aboncode, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_transactionid", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_transactionid, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_abontype", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_abontype, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_namesurname", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_namesurname, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_debt", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_debt, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_date", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_date, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("o_time", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, o_time, ParameterDirection.Output);


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            string messagetype = o_messagetype;
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
           // label1.Text = ex.Message;
          //  textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
          richTextBox1.Text= ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Удается ли выполнить ваш код средствами оракла?

Comment: тот же процедуру использовал на PHP script-e там никаких проблем не возникает

Comment: А сообщение об ошибке не удалось полностью вытянуть? Проверте в оригинале на наличие не принтабельных символов.

Comment: 1. PL/SQL код приведен не полностью. Оракл ругается на символ 330, а у вас их всего 310; 2. В таком виде вы не вернете результат из `v_return`, вам надо писать что-то вроде `begin :v_result := ode.get_borc(...`